# Как реализовать промокод с помощью PHP?

Tags: php

В корзине есть специальное поле(`input` например), в который если ввести необходимое значение - цена(вводимая js'ом) покупки должна уменьшиться.

Как я понимаю необходимо в БД создать специальное поле с значениями(промо-кодами) и при вводе n символов проверять - равно ли введенное пользователем значение промо-коду.

Так вот собственно вопросы:

1. Как вызывать в html php код проверяющий правильность промо-кода?
2. Можно ли добавить графический интерфейс позволяющий введя пароль\логин базы данных создавать, удалять, изменять промокоды?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как вызывать в html php код проверяющий правильность промо-кода?

PHP код проверяющий правильность промо-кода должен работать на стороне сервера, там же и должна быть база данных, с которой этот самый PHP код будет взаимодействовать. Схема примерно следующая:

1. На сервере запускается PHP скрипт, который доступен по какому-то адресу (например, http://check-my-promo.com)
2. В запросе можно отправить параметр, например promo (итоговый URL будет выглядеть так - http://check-my-promo.com?promo=155454545, где 155454545 это ваш промо-код
3. PHP скрипт получит из GET массива ваш параметр promo и произведет проверку, а затем отдаст какой-то ответ (например строку "YES" или какие-то еще данные)
4. На вашей странице при вводе данных в форму вы AJAX'ом отправляете значение вашего input'а в качестве значения параметра promo в вашем URL, получаете ответ, что-то делаете с этим ответом.

Это вкратце. На самом деле нюансов может быть больше, например, если вам нужно сформировать форму, отправка которой сформирует какой-то заказ в БД и прочее, но это уже другая история.

> Можно ли добавить графический интерфейс позволяющий введя пароль\логин
>   базы данных создавать, удалять, изменять промокоды?

Это, в большинстве случаев, опять же какой-то скрипт, или целое приложение, работающее на сервере, написанное на том же PHP или каком-то ином серверном языке. Это приложение отдает в ответе HTML который и является по сути интерфейсом. Если вам нужно просто управлять базой, а не специализированная админка - можно поставить какой-нибудь phpMyAdmin или воспользоваться софтом для удаленного подключения к базе (например Navicat). Если нужна именно админка - нужно ее писать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разьяснения, теперь всё стало понятнее.

Comment: В частности сам сайт у меня уже стоит на хостинге на MODX, где есть установленная phpMyAdmin.

Comment: В таком случае как вы считаете, как с помощью phpMyAdmin Будет понятнее обычному заказчику создавать и т.д. промокоды? Просто мне кажется что будет сложновато ему разобраться в этом

Comment: @Кевин заказчику обычно не следует лезть в базу, по хорошему это должна быть какая-то мини-панель управления